# How to add radius to <thead> in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I was trying to add some radius to  tag in Bootstrap. But I tried all the ways and I couldn't add. If you want more details pls let me know about what you wanna learn. By the way I tried to add radius to `<tr>` tag inside the `<thead>` but didn't work too. Here is my codes:

HTML

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Sıra</th>
      <th>İsim</th>
      <th>Altın</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td><img src="https://minotar.net/helm/CmJustice/20"> CmJustice</td>
      <td>123123</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">2</th>
      <td><img src="https://minotar.net/helm/CmJustice/20"> CmJustice</td>
      <td>123123</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">3</th>
      <td><img src="https://minotar.net/helm/CmJustice/20"> CmJustice</td>
      <td>124123123</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td><img src="https://minotar.net/helm/CmJustice/20"> CmJustice</td>
      <td>123123</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">2</th>
      <td><img src="https://minotar.net/helm/CmJustice/20"> CmJustice</td>
      <td>123123</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">3</th>
      <td><img src="https://minotar.net/helm/CmJustice/20"> CmJustice</td>
      <td>124123123</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td><img src="https://minotar.net/helm/CmJustice/20"> CmJustice</td>
      <td>123123</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">2</th>
      <td><img src="https://minotar.net/helm/CmJustice/20"> CmJustice</td>
      <td>123123</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">3</th>
      <td><img src="https://minotar.net/helm/CmJustice/20"> CmJustice</td>
      <td>124123123</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">3</th>
      <td><img src="https://minotar.net/helm/CmJustice/20"> CmJustice</td>
      <td>124123123</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS

```
thead {
  background-color: #E0E0E0;
  border: 3px;
  border-color: #E0E0E0;
  border-radius: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Why m  feeling that this question is just asked here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37963524/how-to-apply-border-radius-to-tr-in-bootstrap

Comment: You would need to add border-radius to `th` instead of `thead`

Comment: but i want the <thead> tag be radiused. not the each th

Comment: You'll have to do it via the first th and the last th in thead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can even try adding like this by adding class to your tr, as below. Actually it is possible to add background-color of thead but using the old method bgcolor, which doesn't works using css3.

```
<thead>
<tr class="brd">
  <th>Sıra</th>
  <th>İsim</th>
  <th>Altın</th>
</tr>
</thead>

.brd{
background-color:#ccc;
}
.brd > th:nth-child(1){
background:#ccc;
border-radius:30px 0px 0px 30px;
}
.brd > th:nth-child(3){
background:#ccc;
border-radius:0px 30px 30px 0px;
}
tbody{
border-top:3px solid #fff;
}
```

Using tbody I have changes that border of color grey to white.

Comment: Welcome @AlperBerber

Answer (score 4):

You cant apply a `border-radius` directly to the `thead`. You could apply it to the first and last `th` to give the same effect.

```css
thead th {
  background-color: #E0E0E0;
}
thead th:first-child {
  border-radius: 100px 0 0 100px;
}
thead th:last-child {
  border-radius: 0 100px 100px 0;
}

/* remove border from th... */
/* !important is only required in stack snippet, probably not in your production code */

.table > thead > tr > th {
  border: none !important;
}

/* remove border from first tbody row... */
.table > tbody > tr:first-child > td,
.table > tbody > tr:first-child > th {
  border-top: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Sıra</th>
      <th>İsim</th>
      <th>Altın</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td>
        <img src="https://minotar.net/helm/CmJustice/20">CmJustice</td>
      <td>123123</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">2</th>
      <td>
        <img src="https://minotar.net/helm/CmJustice/20">CmJustice</td>
      <td>123123</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">3</th>
      <td>
        <img src="https://minotar.net/helm/CmJustice/20">CmJustice</td>
      <td>124123123</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td>
        <img src="https://minotar.net/helm/CmJustice/20">CmJustice</td>
      <td>123123</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">2</th>
      <td>
        <img src="https://minotar.net/helm/CmJustice/20">CmJustice</td>
      <td>123123</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">3</th>
      <td>
        <img src="https://minotar.net/helm/CmJustice/20">CmJustice</td>
      <td>124123123</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td>
        <img src="https://minotar.net/helm/CmJustice/20">CmJustice</td>
      <td>123123</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">2</th>
      <td>
        <img src="https://minotar.net/helm/CmJustice/20">CmJustice</td>
      <td>123123</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">3</th>
      <td>
        <img src="https://minotar.net/helm/CmJustice/20">CmJustice</td>
      <td>124123123</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">3</th>
      <td>
        <img src="https://minotar.net/helm/CmJustice/20">CmJustice</td>
      <td>124123123</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, i guess thats the best way to nail it :)

Comment: But as you can see there is small line left at the bottom of the block. Do you have any idea to remove it ?

Comment: @AlperBerber then you have to use border-top:0 for first child.

Comment: thead th:first-child {
  border-top: 0;
  border-radius: 100px 0 0 100px;
}
thead th:last-child {
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-radius: 0 100px 100px 0;
    } still looks same? the little line at the top of <pre>thead</pre> is gone but the other one at the bottom is still there

Comment: sorry for that mess. I dunno how to add code in comments.

Comment: Did you see the update? You use the ` character to format comment code.

Answer (score 0):

Building upon @Turnip's answer You could do something like..

Look at the "Table Border Fix" in CSS section

[DEMO](http://codepen.io/MohdAbdulMujib/pen/Nrbaqj)

```css
thead th {
  background-color: #E0E0E0;
}
thead th:first-child {
  border-radius: 100px 0 0 100px;
}
thead th:last-child {
  border-radius: 0 100px 100px 0;
}
/** Border Fix. **/
table th {
  border: none !important;
}
table td {
  border: none !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Sıra</th>
      <th>İsim</th>
      <th>Altın</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td>
        <img src="https://minotar.net/helm/CmJustice/20">CmJustice</td>
      <td>123123</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">2</th>
      <td>
        <img src="https://minotar.net/helm/CmJustice/20">CmJustice</td>
      <td>123123</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">3</th>
      <td>
        <img src="https://minotar.net/helm/CmJustice/20">CmJustice</td>
      <td>124123123</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td>
        <img src="https://minotar.net/helm/CmJustice/20">CmJustice</td>
      <td>123123</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">2</th>
      <td>
        <img src="https://minotar.net/helm/CmJustice/20">CmJustice</td>
      <td>123123</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">3</th>
      <td>
        <img src="https://minotar.net/helm/CmJustice/20">CmJustice</td>
      <td>124123123</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td>
        <img src="https://minotar.net/helm/CmJustice/20">CmJustice</td>
      <td>123123</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">2</th>
      <td>
        <img src="https://minotar.net/helm/CmJustice/20">CmJustice</td>
      <td>123123</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">3</th>
      <td>
        <img src="https://minotar.net/helm/CmJustice/20">CmJustice</td>
      <td>124123123</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">3</th>
      <td>
        <img src="https://minotar.net/helm/CmJustice/20">CmJustice</td>
      <td>124123123</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```